# Procmail/munpack: Extracting headers similar to text and attachments?

Tags: linux, email, procmail, fetchmail

I currently have set up fetchmail to transfer mail to procmail and a .procmailrc file with the following content:

```
FILE_DIR=$HOME/incoming
:0
* 
| munpack -q -C "$FILE_DIR"
```

If I receive emails with attachments, munpack will create a file123.ext and a file123.desc, the latter containing the text of the email. However, the headers are lost. Is there a way to save the headers of the email to a file123.headers file or something like that or, better yet, make munpack save the whole message - including headers - in the .desc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily save the headers separately, but of course you can't predict which file name `munpack` will assign to the extracted message.

```
:0hc
headers

:0
| munpack -q -C "$FILE_DIR"
```

This simply writes the headers to `headers`. Perhaps you could add some logic around this to create a new directory for each incoming message, or something like that.

(Notice also how you simply omit the condition line if you want to deliver unconditionally.)

Maybe a better solution would be to switch to a tool which extracts the headers as well. I vaguely recall `ripmime` would be somewhat more flexible than `munpack`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I looked at ripmime and it is indeed more flexible than munpack in that regard :-)